# explore multiple GB of JSON data

Tags: json, large-data

I’ve got a live firebase app with a database that’s about 5GB in size. The firebase dashboard refuses to show me the contents of my database and just fails to load every time, presumably because the thing is too big. I’ve been digging around for some time now in search of some tool that makes it possible for me to come up with an ERD of my data. Help?

Atom crashes, vim takes forever and doesnt load anything, jq simply spits out a formatted version of my data, i’ve tried a couple of java tools to generate JSON schemas, but they crash after a while.. most python programs to do the same don’t even start properly.

How would you explore 5GB of json data?

Comment: You would be better off, it at all possible, to devide your data into smaller, self contained chunks.

Comment: I can't do that unfortunately

Comment: If the JSON is stored in a file, for example containing an array or a dictionary with millions of entries, then it is not difficult to write a program that will split this file into dozens of files each containing valid JSON, but only  an array or dictionary with say 20,000 entries each. Although you won't be able to do this with a plain JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the file editors have line pagination, so your file should load. 
Unless it's a one single line file.
In that case, you can use `sed` or `jq` to reformat the file in order to have more than one line.

After that operation you should be able to open it.
In case you need to extract data, you could use `cat file.json | grep "what you need to extract"`.
That should work even on a one single line 5gb file.